# Troubles with partial content nginx

Tags: django, google-chrome, nginx, gunicorn, nginx-location

I get some video files from server and use in templates like this:

```
<div class="player-block" ng-if='hasSubscription(episode_detail.season)'>
                                    <video ng-if='episode_detail' id="serial-video" class="video-js" controls preload="none" height="450" data-setup="{}">
                                        <source ng-src="{{episode_detail.video_mp}}" type='video/mp4'>
                                        <source ng-src="{{episode_detail.video}}" type='video/webm'>
                                        <p class="vjs-no-js">
                                            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
                                            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
                                        </p>
                                    </video>
                                </div>
```

my nginx config:
[image]

[image]

Thats what i mean, try to rewind video in google chrome:
http://185.143.173.143:8000/media/SPONGEBOB_TRAP_REMIX_KRUSTY_KRAB_Vine_Remix.mp4

The result is not working in chrome rewind , I read that it is necessary to configure the server to return partial content.How do I configure nginx for this?

Answer (score 2):

You have `max_ranges` set to 0, which will disable Range request handling in nginx. The simplest thing to do would be to remove that `max_ranges 0` line. However, that still might not work if the origin (185.143.173.143) does not honor the Range requests.

In order to test if the origin (185.143.173.143) itself supports range requests, you will want to use curl from your nginx machine:

```
curl -I -r 0-100 http://185.143.173.143/path/to/video
```

If the `Range` request worked, the status will be something like `206 Partial Content` and there will be a `Content-Range` header indicating the requested range. The `Content-Length` should be 101 in this case. If you get a 200 then likely your actual origin itself does not support range requests, and you will have to debug the configuration there.

Comment: please tell me how to fix it

Comment: I thought I did :) Try removing the max_ranges 0 line from the config. But if the origin itself doesn't support ranges, there's not much you can do easily

Comment: max ranges removed , nothing has changed

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gunicorn/19.4.5
Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 19:54:58 GMT
Connection: close
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Length: 5366667
Content-Type: video/mp4
Last-Modified: Sun, 17 Jul 2016 19:29:44 GMT
"My output"

Comment: But if i use curl -I -r 0-100 http://185.143.173.143
 I get:HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 20:14:04 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 101
Last-Modified: Fri, 08 Jul 2016 12:46:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "577fa0b7-264"
Content-Range: bytes 0-100/612